# Selenium Error - [error] Element //div[@id='sizzle-1452751603178']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5] not found

Tags: java, selenium

I am very new to programming and Selenium. I am trying to start Automation for a project and i am stuck on this scenario -

Scenario -

I am trying to record a functionality where i am creating a new user on a page. This page has a date section, where i need to select the date from the calendar. This is the first point of issue. I am getting the following error when i re-play the script -

```
[info] Executing: |click | //div[@id='sizzle-1452751603178']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5] | |
[error] Element //div[@id='sizzle-1452751603178']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5] not found
```

Can someone please help out. Please let me know how to handle such situation as this application has hell of forms to be filled in and has a date like this one every section.

Comment: add html of date picker. you may have to first hover on datepicker to show it on the screen, then click.  are you using selenium ide?

Comment: please relevant html code and stacktrace also if you can replicate this on a public URL that would be best